# What career can a master student take?

Tags: career-path, research-undergraduate

So I normally see master graduate student apply for a position as a lecturer.

Is there any other career that is available for a master (science) student asides from lecturer? Which is for computer science students

Comment: In what area? A lot of my Master colleagues in Computer Science are working in software development companies of all types: private, public, government, etc... So, I would say that "go to the industry" is always a viable option, whatever area you are referring.

Answer (score 3):

For a career in academia you basically need a doctorate. There are jobs for secondary school teachers and low level jobs at university. The secondary school positions are actually better than the low-level university positions, in most cases, however. Many places require additional certification for high school jobs, of course.

Most people who earn an MS/MA either go on for more learning or head to industry/government where there are positions available. If you want to do research but without a doctorate, the best place is in some industry lab or (for CS) a software development company. The research will be pretty applied, however.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your local jobs portal and search for "master" + "[insert name of your field]". You'll find more answers there than you can here, and those results are tailored for you as well.

For example, suppose I'm in Indiana, USA and have a Masters in computer science. Performing [this search](https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=master+computer+science&l=United+States+indiana) on Indeed.com yields jobs like [this one](https://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=b8ee0428dfc5245e&tk=1d05v3secbuoq800&from=serp&vjs=3). Look through the list and see what's out there for you.